# TypeError when calling methods on nested functions

Tags: javascript, class, data-structures, methods

I am attempting to create a graph using two classes (Node and Graph).  I am able to construct a basic graph.  However, when calling the addChild method to add a child node to the children property of a nested node, I am receiving the following type error.  Can anyone advise how to fix this type error?

**TypeError: graph.root.children[0].addChild is not a function**

```
class Node {

    name = '';
    children = [];

    constructor() {}

    createNode(name, childNames) {
        this.name = name;
        childNames.forEach(childName => {
            this.children.push({name: childName, children: []});
        });
        return { name: this.name,
            children: this.children};
    } // createNode
}

class Graph {
    root = new Node();
    constructor(node) {
        const { name, children } = node;
        this.root = {
            name,
            children
        };
    }
    addChild(node) {
        console.log("Graph", JSON.stringify(node));
        this.root.children.push(node);
    }
}
// Add the three child nodes under node A's children property (B (this.root.children[0]), C(this.root.children[1]), D(this.root.children[2]))
const rootNode = new Node();
rootNode.createNode('A', ['B', 'C', 'D']);
const graph = new Graph(rootNode);
// rootNode = new Node().createNode();
// add to bNode this.root.children[0]
const eNode = new Node();
eNode.createNode('E', []);

const fNode = new Node();
fNode.createNode('F', []);

console.log(`Graph: ${JSON.stringify(graph)}`);

console.log(`graph: ${JSON.stringify(graph.root.children[0])}`);
graph.root.children[0].addChild(eNode);
```

Comment: You are calling `addChild()` on a `Node` object instead of calling it on the  `Graph` object, where the method belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if its too hard to read, but I commented on your class with what I think is an error or could be improved, and at the end gave my solution based on the improvements I've commented about.

```
class Node {
    /* 
        I assume this is for backup? 
        but this dosn't work becouse every instance of the Node object as that property, 
        even if its value is undefined.
        So it's better to just give defualt values in the constructor
    */
    name = '';
    children = [];
/*
    childNames is an array of what? ['A', 'B'] or [{name: 'A', children: []}, ... ]
    second case → you should make sure that they are instances of Node,
    so you can use the addChild methos
*/

//for default values: (name='', childNames=[])

constructor(name, childNames) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = childNames;
    // if this children are not nodes you can't use the addChild method 
}

createNodeWithChildren(name, childNames) {
    /* 
        There are a few problems with this method:
        1. the name of the method, createNodeWithChildren,
           you aren't even creating a node, but recreating it. 
        2. you are modifying the node object with the keyword 'this',
           and than returning a new Node object that isn't even saved
           in a variable
        →  or you use the 'this' keywor or return a new object, but like I
           sad you should create a new node with children and not a children 
           on an existing node
    */

    // 'this' points at the eNode Object → {name: 'E', children: []}
    this.name = name; 
    // → {name: 'E', children: []}
    const childArray = [];   // don't know why is here
    this.children = childNames.map(childName => {
        return { name: childName, children: [] };
    }); 
    /*  
        → {name: 'E', children: [{ name: 'Q', children: [] }, { name: 'R', children: [] }]}
        they are non-instance of Node, they aren't real nodes but similar objects, so you 
        can't use the addChild method on them
    */
    console.log(`${this.name}: ${JSON.stringify(this.children)}`);
    return new Node( this.name, this.children);
}

/*
    in the end you are still passing a children variable, so why not have
    only one method to add the node and children?
*/
    addChild({ name, children }) {
        const newNode = new Node(name, children);
        console.log("NODE", JSON.stringify(newNode));
        this.children.push(newNode);
    }
}

    // Graph is just a handle to a bunch of nodes.  Add the three child nodes under node A's children property (B (this.root.children[0]), C(this.root.children[1]), D(this.root.children[2]))
    const graph = new Node('A', []);
    const bNode = new Node('B', []);
    const cNode = new Node('C', []);
    const dNode = new Node('D', []);
    graph.addChild(bNode);
    graph.addChild(cNode);
    graph.addChild(dNode);
    
/*************************************/
// add to bNode this.root.children[0]
let eNode = new Node('E', []);
eNode.createNodeWithChildren('E', ['Q', 'R']);
//createNodeWithChildren return a new Node object, but you aren't saving it
//the value of eNode changed because of the keyword this
//either you return a value or use the this keyword
console.log(`new Enode:`, JSON.stringify(eNode));

let fNode = new Node('F', []);
graph.children[0].addChild(eNode);
graph.children[0].addChild(fNode);
console.log(`Graph: ${JSON.stringify(graph)}`);


/*
    TESTS
*/
 
// 1. show values of empty node object 
let d = new Node();
console.log(d);
// → Node { name: undefined, children: undefined }


// 2. are the children of eNode real nodes? 
console.log(eNode.children[0] instanceof Node);
// → false
console.log(eNode.children.addChild);
// → false
```

MY SOLUTION:
Because this graph is basically a tree, I named it TreeNode

```
class TreeNode {
    // TreeNode Object = {name: 'A', children: [{name: 'B', children: []}, {name: 'C', children: []}]}
    //childNames = array of TreeNode Objects
    constructor(name = '', childNames = []) {
        this.name = name;
        //makes sure the child object is an instance of this class
        this.children = childNames.map((childName) => new TreeNode(childName, []));
    }

    addChild(node) {
        //you can add a child to an already existent node or create one
        if(!(node instanceof TreeNode)) {
            const {name, children} = node;
            node = new TreeNode(name, children);
        }
        console.log("NODE", JSON.stringify(node));
        this.children.push(node);
    }

}

//root node
const tree  = new TreeNode('A', ['B', 'C']);

//non-root nodes
const eNode = new TreeNode('E', []);
const fNode = new TreeNode('F', []);

/*************************************/

//adding children
tree.children[0].addChild({name: 'D', children: ['H']}); //non-instance
tree.children[1].addChild(eNode);  //instance of TreeNode


console.log(tree);
console.log(tree.children[0]);
console.log(tree.children[0].children[0]);
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was trying to create.  Thanks for being so thorough!

Answer (score 0):

the first thing is that you called addChild() on a Node object,
the second is that you are searching for a root property in the child node

this is my quick solution:

```
addChild(node) {
    console.log("Graph", JSON.stringify(node));
    this.children.push(node);
}
```

graph.addChild.call(graph.root.children[0], eNode);
console.log(`graph: ${JSON.stringify(graph.root.children[0])}`);

Comment: Thx for your response.  Your feedback put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback,  all objects need to be declared as Node Objects, in order to call the addChild method on nested objects.  See new class below:

```
class Node {
    name = '';
    children = [];

    constructor(name, childNames) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = childNames;
    }

    createNodeWithChildren(name, childNames) {
        this.name = name;
        const childArray = [];
        this.children = childNames.map(childName => {
            return { name: childName, children: [] };
        });
        console.log(`${this.name}: ${JSON.stringify(this.children)}`);
        return new Node( this.name, this.children);
    } // createNode

    addChild({ name, children }) {
        const newNode = new Node(name, children);
        console.log("NODE", JSON.stringify(newNode));
        this.children.push(newNode);
    }
}

// Graph is just a handle to a bunch of nodes.  Add the three child nodes under node A's children property (B (this.root.children[0]), C(this.root.children[1]), D(this.root.children[2]))
const graph = new Node('A', []);
const bNode = new Node('B', []);
const cNode = new Node('C', []);
const dNode = new Node('D', []);
graph.addChild(bNode);
graph.addChild(cNode);
graph.addChild(dNode);

/*************************************/
// add to bNode this.root.children[0]
let eNode = new Node('E', []);
eNode.createNodeWithChildren('E', ['Q', 'R']);
console.log(`new Enode:`, JSON.stringify(eNode));

let fNode = new Node('F', []);
graph.children[0].addChild(eNode);
graph.children[0].addChild(fNode);
console.log(`Graph: ${JSON.stringify(graph)}`);
```